# Windows 10 Tablet Browser: soft keyboard very buggy

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, windows-10-mobile, soft-keyboard

I have a tablet html app. Some pages have `<input>` and `<textarea>` together with many other elements: links, menus, texts, ...

- If I don't press any `<input>` or `<textarea>` everything works ok
- As soon as I press one input element, the soft keyboard pops up (as expected).
- After entering some text and hiding the keyboard, **the keyboard pops up again everytime I click anywhere on the webapp** (even in non-focusable elements)

This totally ruins the experience, as you are forced to use the web app with the keyboard always shown.

I have tried many different approaches to manipulate the input focus without any success, like calling `blur()`, `focus()` and related methods on the focused component, containers, window ... but seems nothing but reloading the page resets the keyboard state to keep hidden again until a focusable element is tapped.

My experiments:

- Checked that pressing outside of the `<INPUT> / <TEXTAREA>` causes the focus to be removed: `onblur()` gets called, and `document.activeElement` returns NULL.
- Also tried to manually `blur()` everything in the document after an `onchange` is triggered:`$("input,textarea").blur()` .
- Tried to manually giving the `focus()` to a non-interactive element with a TABINDEX (hacky):

  ```
  <div id="dummyfocus" tabindex="0">
  $("#dummyfocus").focus()
  ```
- I checked that the dummy element in fact receives focus, the `input/textarea` unfocuses, but even in this case, the problem persists.

In Android or IOS everything works as expected: Keyboard will not auto-show if no `<input>` or `<textarea>` is focused.

Any advice? Any funky microsoft-proprietary css tag I haven't heard about? :)

Comment: I have the same issue as you do. It seems that when you hide the keyboard (pressing the close button (x) on the keyboard), the input field still has focus. And when you press anywhere else, but the input field, the keyboard pops up again. However, pressing anywhere for a longer time (long press) will remove the focus from the input, and not show the keyboard again.

Answer (score 1):

I have similar issue, after some digging find out that issue reproducible on Microsoft Edge browser( used in win10 uap as rendering engine).
When clicked anywhere active element becomes **body** element and for some reason (maybe bug) keyboard gets activated, so I added tabindex=0 on container div which is nested in body, so when clicked outside of any focus-able element that container becomes activated element and keyboard popup isn't fired.
for checking which element is activated I used this code

```
  document.body.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log(document.activeElement);
  });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I also found this kind of workaround, but unfortunately doesn't solve the problem (you have to add `tabindex=x` to every element in the DOM) and even in that case, many times the keyboard pops-up then disappears when you click on a tabindexed element. As much as I've researched this issue I'm convinced more and more it's a (very annoying) bug :(

Answer (score 1):

I managed to resolve this by adding the following if you are still interested. Added a dummy control to take the focus then change the focus when clicking away from the text area.

```js
$("body").click(function () {
    $("#radioDummy").focus();
});
$("#MyTextArea").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: hey thats very clever indeed! As radio buttons will cause the keyboard to hide. Will try it !

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue lies in the `touchstart` event when using the keyboard on Windows 10. When you hide the keyboard (e.g. pressing the close button (x) on the keyboard), the input field still has focus. And when you press anywhere else, the keyboard pops up again. However, pressing anywhere for a longer time (long press) will remove the focus from the input, and not show the keyboard again. This got me thinking, that the problem could be solved hooking up the `touchstart` event, and prevent the event propagation, and remove the focus from the input.

I created a global `@HostListener` inside my main `AppComponent` that listens for `touchstart` events. When the body is clicked, stop the propagation of the event, and call `document.activeElement.blur()` (Loose focus).

```
@HostListener('document:touchstart', ['$event'])
globalTouchEvent(event) {
    if (event) event.stopPropagation();
    document.activeElement.blur();
}
```

I have created a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-keyboard-focus) that you can test using a Windows 10 tablet.